# Error building Chromium for android in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, chromium

I am trying to build Chromium for Android on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine as an Android Studio project.

I followed instructions from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Installing-and-Running-Chromium-on-a-device/) and [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md) and created a gradle project successfully. But there are many build errors after importing it in Android Studio (3.1.2 stable).

Command to generate gradle project -

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default --project-dir ~/Projects/chromium_source/gradle_project
```

Errors in Android Studio -

**Build Project**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url.url_unittests_apk:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform file 'junit.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/junit/junit.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'hamcrest-core.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/hamcrest/hamcrest-core.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'ub-uiautomator.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/ub-uiautomator/ub-uiautomator.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'runner-release-no-dep.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/android_support_test_runner/runner-release-no-dep.jar does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'exposed-instrumentation-api-publish-no-dep.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/android_support_test_runner/exposed-instrumentation-api-publish-no-dep.jar   does not exist.
> Failed to transform file 'rules_java.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
> Transform output file /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/android_support_test_runner/rules_java.jar does not exist.

build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default --target //chrome/android:chrome_public_apk
```

**Make module chrome.android.chrome_public_apk**

```
    /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/base/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/process_launcher/ChildProcessConnection.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import org.chromium.base.MemoryPressureLevel;
                        ^
  symbol:   class MemoryPressureLevel
  location: package org.chromium.base
/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/base/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/process_launcher/ChildProcessConnection.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
    private IChildProcessService mService;
            ^
  symbol:   class IChildProcessService
  location: class ChildProcessConnection
/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/base/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/library_loader/LibraryLoader.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import org.chromium.base.BuildConfig;
                        ^
  symbol:   class BuildConfig
  location: package org.chromium.base
/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/chrome/android/feed/core/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/feed/action/FeedActionHandler.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import org.chromium.ui.base.PageTransition;
                           ^
  symbol:   class PageTransition
  location: package org.chromium.ui.base
/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/chrome/android/feed/core/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/feed/action/FeedActionHandler.java:14: error: package org.chromium.ui.mojom does not exist
import org.chromium.ui.mojom.WindowOpenDisposition;
                            ^
/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content_public/browser/LoadUrlParams.java:9: error: package org.chromium.content_public.browser.navigation_controller does not exist
import org.chromium.content_public.browser.navigation_controller.LoadURLType;

/home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/tab/Tab.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
import org.chromium.chrome.R;
                          ^
  symbol:   class R
  location: package org.chromium.chrome
:chrome.android.chrome_public_apk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

**Update**:

Adding the *--full* flag to the command adds *extracted-srcjars* and *extracted-res* folders containing all of the missing dependencies. This however, hangs my machine completely, unless I build the targets selectively.

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default --full --target //chrome/android:chrome_public_apk --target //chrome/android:chrome_junit_tests
```

I had to make some additional changes in *chrome_public_apk* build.gradle to fix some more errors -

1. `cannot find symbol class GeneratedMessageLite`

   Remove this line from *java.filter.exclude*
   `"com/google/protobuf/*.java"`
2. `duplicate class: com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite`

   Replace in *java.srcDirs*

   `"../../../../src/third_party/android_protobuf/src/java/src/main/java"`

   by

   `"../../../../src/third_party/android_protobuf/src/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/nano"`
3. `cannot access ViewerType
   class file for com.google.vr.ndk.base.GvrApi$ViewerType not found`

   Replace in *dependencies* block

   `"../../../../src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/gvr-android-sdk/gvr_common_java.jar"`

   by

   `"../../../../src/out/Default/lib.java/third_party/gvr-android-sdk/gvr_common_java.interface.jar"`

The compiler errors are gone, but fails with the following error -

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/sagarjoshi/Projects/chromium_source/gradle_full_chrome_public/chrome/android/chrome_public_apk/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/18.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:550)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$1(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing com/google/vr/ndk/base/GvrApi.class

    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:89)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:545)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext
    at com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(ExceptionWithContext.java:45)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:150)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:102)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.dex(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveBuilder.convert(DxDexArchiveBuilder.java:86)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:80)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.<init>(ConcreteMethod.java:69)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:300)
    ... 11 more
```

I have also tried using the D8 dexer; didn't help.

Comment: did you able to build chromium for the android studio?

Answer (score 1):

How frustrating! Looks like you may be missing some tests. Have you tried specifying the targets and ensuring to include the tests? I think it should be something like...

```
build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py \
    --output-directory out/Default \
    --project-dir ~/Projects/chromium_source/gradle_project \
    --target '//chrome/android:chrome_public_apk' \
    --target '//chrome/android:chrome_junit_tests'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it helps when used along with the --full flag, but I'm still facing errors. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Billy Lazzaro, did you able to build chromium for android studio?